# Inner funtion gives error in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have inner functions inside the main function with an IF statement but when the if condition is applied it gives this error (AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.)

How can I solve this issue? Any help, please?

views.py

```
from .api_option23 import api_option23
from .api_option45 import api_option45

@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def apiscanning(request, qrcode, action, curr_user):
    if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST":
     if action ==1:
       #do something 
    
    elif action ==2:
       api_option23(request, identifer,
        qr_code_id,
        qr_pks,
        loggeduser,
        actions)

    elif action ==3:
       api_option45(request, identifer,
        qr_code_id,
        qr_pks,
        loggeduser,
        actions)
```

api_option23.py

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def api_option23(request, identifer, qr_code_id, qr_pks, loggeduser, actions):
    if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST":
        nowdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        security_men = SecurityUser.objects.filter(name=loggeduser)
        if security_men:
           for men in security_men:
              username_id = men.pk
              sec_location = men.sec_location
           print(security_men, username_id, sec_location, qr_pks)
```

api_option45.py

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def api_option45(request, identifer, qr_code_id, qr_pks, loggeduser, actions):
    if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST":
        nowdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        security_men = SecurityUser.objects.filter(name=loggeduser)
        if security_men:  # 1
          for men in security_men:
            username_id = men.pk
            sec_location = men.sec_location
         print(security_men, username_id, sec_location)
```

[image: this image shows the inner functions and the main one are within one app]

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to give you an answer. Could you show api_method_23(), the request object you're passing to the function, and what line the error is occuring on?

Comment: Please add those details to the original question.

Comment: @Rufus, Hi.. I updated the question.